# Guice generics config error from static class/interface

Tags: java, generics, guice, typeliteral

I'm running into an error trying to get guice wired up. Here's some sample code that reproduces the issue I'm seeing:

```
public class GuiceGenerics<K, V> {

    public static interface Foo<K, V> {

    }

    public static class FooImpl<K, V> implements Foo<K, V> {

    }

    public static class FooModule extends PrivateModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(new TypeLiteral<Foo<String, Integer>>(){}).to(new TypeLiteral<FooImpl<String, Integer>>(){});

            bind(new TypeLiteral<GuiceGenerics<String, Integer>>(){});
            expose(new TypeLiteral<GuiceGenerics<String, Integer>>(){});
        }
    }

    private Foo<K, V> foo;

    @Inject
    public GuiceGenerics(Foo<K, V> foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new FooModule());
        GuiceGenerics<String, Integer> guiceGenerics = injector.getInstance(GuiceGenerics.class);
    }
}
```

When I run main(), I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) com.knewton.recommendationservice.retries.GuiceGenerics$Foo<K, V> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
  at com.knewton.recommendationservice.retries.GuiceGenerics.<init>(GuiceGenerics.java:36)
  while locating com.knewton.recommendationservice.retries.GuiceGenerics

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at com.knewton.recommendationservice.retries.GuiceGenerics.main(GuiceGenerics.java:42)
```

I get the feeling that I'm using TypeLiteral incorrectly, but I can't figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure, your `getInstance()` call can't work.  Do this instead:

```
GuiceGenerics<String, Integer> guiceGenerics =
        injector.getInstance(new Key<GuiceGenerics<String, Integer>>() { });
```